# How do I import Bulma Carousel in Angular 10?

Tags: angular, bulma

I'm trying to import Bulma carousel, https://github.com/wikiki/bulma-carousel into an angular 10 app.

- I've got the javascript imported via angular.json.
- In the component the carousel is going to be displayed in I tried importing the class and accessing it

  ```
  import {bulmaCarousel} from 'bulma-carousel';
  ...
  ngOnInit(): void {


  this.carousel = bulmaCarousel.attach('#carousel-demo', {
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    slidesToShow: 4
  });
  ```

I get an error message

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'attach' of undefined at HomeComponent.ngOnInit (http:
```

If I try to randomly import it into *app.module*

```
import {bulmaCarousel} from 'bulma-carousel';
...
imports [
  bulmaCarousel
```

I get

```
ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts:71:12 - error NG1010: Value at position 16 in the NgModule.imports of AppModule is not a reference: [object Object]
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work, home.component.ts:

```
import {bulmaCarousel} from 'bulma-carousel']

declare var bulmaCarousel: any;
```

Then load the library in ngOnInit().